# Bluetooth settings page opens and closes right away

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I am trying to open Bluetooth settings on my Windows 10 machine. The blue settings window displaying a cog opens for a second and then closes again.
Bluetooth itself works fine as I have a Bluetooth mouse and a Bluetooth speaker that are functional.

I just can't open the Bluetooth settings app. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Try the initial Windows 10 repair and see if that works.  DISM and SFC.  ...... (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I should have also noted, after you have done the above, update / reinstall the Bluetooth Driver.

Comment: @John I ran all the commands you have suggested and then restarted the computer and reinstalled Buetooth. Same issue. I also see an error in Windows Logs -> App events: (short version) `Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe; Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.2130, Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.2.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Bluetooth settings page opens and closes right away  .... DISM/SFC and
> updated driver do not help.

**(1) Run a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. **The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.**
Use Keep Everything to start with,

**(2) Repair Install fails to correct the situation So then you need to reinstall Windows fresh.**

The error you got has some information here.

[Faulting module ntdll.ddd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280250/faulting-module-name-ntdlldll.html)

The operating system has too much damage or the Windows User Profile is damaged.

In either case, the most practical way forward is to back up the system entirely and do a fresh install of Windows 10.  Be sure the backup is complete.

Comment: That didn't help so I guess I'll have to reinstall Windows. What app do you suggest to use for full system backup?

Comment: Acronis is normally a good choice.   Reinstall is the 2nd choice in my solution if you choose to reinstall.

Comment: Assuming you are going to reinstall Windows, you might wish to mark my post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in a command prompt as Administrator:

```
sc config deviceassociationservice start= auto
```

Alternatively, check that the "Device Association Service" in `services.msc` is both running and enabled.

I had this issue and this was the solution. It also fixed an issue where I couldn't add printers.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work - I still see a blue splash screen and then the bluetooth app crashes/closes